# Cómo construir un diagrama de clases desde código PHP

Tags: php, uml

Existe alguna herramienta o plugins que permita generar un diagrama de clases desde código PHP?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahora mismo no hay ninguna herramienta que cumpla estas características, no obstante, sí puedes encontrar herramientas dónde hacer tu diagrama de clases en UML y luego generar su código en PHP.
Te dejo algunas de ellas en el siguiente enlace:

[Información.](http://phpexperto.blogspot.com.es/2008/12/comendo-con-uml-y-php.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[uml](/questions/tagged/uml)